# Looping through functions until value is not null, ramda js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I want a function that returns a value when a function returns a value which is not null.

```
const getSomeValue = R.filter(...);

const getSomeOtherValue = R.propEq('name');
```

The `R.until` function is probably the one to use.

Some pseudo code:

```
R.until(R.isNotNull, R...[getSomeValue, getSomeOtherValue]);
```

So run through the functions until the returned value is not null.

I don't find any suitable function in the Ramda docs to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide a small example with input / output? that would help in understanding what you want to achieve

Comment: Hmm, niether `propEq('name')` nor `filter` would return `null`. Please provide actual functions and inputs you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to also ignore falsy values (false, undefined, 0, etc...) then you could use [`R.either`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#either):

```js
const first = () => {
  console.log("first");
  return null;
};
const second = () => {
  console.log("second");
  return {a: "banana"};
};
const third = () => {
  console.log("third");
  return {a: "chicken"};
};

const fn = R.either(first, second, third);
console.log(fn());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ramda@0.26.1/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```